# Already put } but the error still says that } is expected?

Tags: lua, syntax-error, lua-table

I took this from a tutorial, when i attempted to run it, *a confusing error* appears

```
local t1 = {"hi", true}
local t2 = {79, "bye", false}
local mt = {
    __concat = function(v1, v2)
        local output = {}
        for i, v in pairs(v1) do
            table.insert(output, v)
        end
        for i, v in pairs(v2) do
            table.insert(output, v)
        end
    end
    return output
    }
setmetatable(t1, mt)
setmetatable(t2, mt) --they gotta have it both as well

local t3 = t1..t2 --we merged t1 and t2 together, as you can see you can get creative
print(unpack(t3)) --t3 contains all of t1 and t2's members
```

> The error is : **File:13: '}' expected (to close '{' at line 3) near 'return'**

Comment: My _VERSION is Lua 5.3

Comment: Your `return output` is outside the __concat function; make sure it's inside.

Comment: i actually already tried it before, this is what i got after make it inside the __concat function:  *File:19: attempt to call a nil value (global 'unpack')*

Comment: unpack() seems confusing too, i have read [this](https://www.lua.org/pil/5.1.html) to know about it but i can't really understand anything. Lua keeps returning some weird errors

Comment: Nvm i already discovered the way to fix it. Just add print(table.concat(t3, " ")) then change some boolean values into strings

Comment: The error in the question is because `return output` needs to be placed before the `end` that closes the function definition. The error you report in the comments (_attempt to call a nil value_) is because you need to use `table.unpack()` instead of `unpack()` in Lua 5.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem: you're taking the error message too literally without taking the time to understand it.

Lua isn't just randomly expecting a `}` exactly on line 13, it's expecting something that makes sense in a table literal and finds a `return` instead, so it defaults to tell you the first thing it can think of that would make sense, aka. closing the table with a `}` first.

The *real* problem, is that the `return` is outside of the function, so Lua doesn't know what to make of it. It needs to go above the `end` instead.

Generally speaking: When Lua tells you *Expected something on line X*, you should just read it as *I found something weird on line X and have no idea what you mean*. A better error message would have been *encountered `return` in table literal* I guess.

Comment: I already discovered the way to fix it before uploading this(returning *output* variable inside of the function). But the next error :  *File:19: attempt to call a nil value (global 'unpack')* made me thought  the problem isn't the "return". I tried to check back my codes(but really didn't understand how the error worked), thus, i have to post the original code to make sure that nothing is wrong here. But **Generally speaking** really gives me some good information so thanks